# jQuery/JavaScript Tabs not working for IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, prototypejs

I have this tabs that are working perfect in any browser apart from IE 9. Have been trying to solve this problem for days now, and I think I'm going completely mad.

```
<div class="product-collateral">

         <div class="tab"><h3 class="product_tabs_additional">Additional Information</h3></div>
        <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_additional_contents">
            Additional Information Content
        </div>

        <div class="tab"><h3 class="product_tabs_agenda">Agenda</h3></div>
        <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_agenda_contents">
            Agenda Content
        </div>


        <div class="tab"><h3 class="product_tabs_terms">Terms and Conditions</h3></div>
        <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_terms_contents">
            Terms and Conditions Content
        </div>


        <div class="tab"><h3 class="product_tabs_locations">Locations</h3></div>
        <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_locations_contents">
            Locations Content
    </div></div>
```

​

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
$jQ('.product-collateral .tab h3').wrapAll('<ul class="product-tabs"></ul>').wrap('<li></li>');
$jQ('.product-collateral .product-tabs li').each(function(index) {
    $jQ(this).attr('id', $jQ(this).find('h3').attr('class'));
    if (index === 0) {
        $jQ(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
//<![CDATA[
Varien.Tabs = Class.create();
Varien.Tabs.prototype = {
    initialize: function(selector) {
        var self = this;
        $$(selector + ' h3').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
    },

    initTab: function(el) {
        el.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
        if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {
            this.showContent(el);
        }
        el.observe('click', this.showContent.bind(this, el));
    },

    showContent: function(a) {
        var li = $(a.parentNode),
            ul = $(li.parentNode);
        ul.select('li', 'ol').each(function(el) {
            var contents = $(el.id + '_contents');
            if (el == li) {
                el.addClassName('active');
                contents.show();
            } else {
                el.removeClassName('active');
                contents.hide();
            }
        });
    }
}
new Varien.Tabs('.product-tabs');
//]]>
< /script>​
```

I know that one of the lines  `$$(selector + ' h3').each(this.initTab.bind(this));` there is a 2x$ but without it script stops working.

Im not a JavaScript specialist at all, hence my problem. Strangest for me is that this script is running in IE7 and 8 mode without any trouble. Only IE9 is breaking.

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Dom

Comment: Do you have the [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/) library included too?  That library uses `$$` to mean select elements matching a given query string, which is probably what's going on  with that line you refer to.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please Check you code, and avoid declaring multiple versions of jQuery on the page. I think its the problem of jQuery conflict.**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your page, you are using an old version of prototype (1.6.0.3), which was released in 2008 which is pre-IE9.  In this version when you run the line: `ul.select('li', 'ol')` it's returning the empty list instead of the 4 element list you expect.

**Quick fix**: try changing the line to: `ul.select('li')`, which should select all the elements you want here.

**Better fix**: Upgrade to the latest version of [prototype (1.7)](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js).

Comment: Thank you Mark. I have tried to add this but still no results. Can I show you the website. Thanks so much for your help. http://www.govouchers.co.uk/go-extreme/go-bungee/london-bungee-jump-o2-arena.html